# lightning Error Case: id value of incorrect type: at Edit Case Type

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforcedx

I am trying to edit an existing ERT case type which is a child to Case object by overriding standard EDIT buttin in ERT case record ,here is error

[image]

I am using use Philippe Ozil's ready [component](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup) for the lookup/autocomplete thing. copied save LookupSearchResult class, the whole aura component and 2 aura events in my org ..here is controller apex

```
            public with sharing class ERT_MultiLevelSelectEdit {
                @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
                public static List<LookupSearchResult> search(String searchTerm, List<String> selectedIds){
                    if(String.isBlank(searchTerm) || searchTerm.length() < 2){
                        return null;
                    }
                    String t = '%' + searchTerm + '%'; 
                    
                    List<Case_Type_Data__c> records =  [FIND :('*' + searchTerm + '*') IN ALL FIELDS 
                    RETURNING Case_Type_Data__c(Id, Name, Level_1__c, Level_2__c, Level_3__c)][0];
                    
                 
                    
                    List<LookupSearchResult> results = new List<LookupSearchResult>();
                    for(Case_Type_Data__c ctd : records){
                        results.add(new LookupSearchResult(ctd.Id, 'Case_Type_Data__c', 'standard:case_wrap_up', ctd.Name,
                            String.join(new List<String>{ctd.Level_1__c , ctd.Level_2__c, ctd.Level_3__c}, '; ')
                        ));
                    }
                    return results;
                } 
            }
```

Here is `cmp`

```
            <aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:actionOverride" access="global" controller="ERT_MultiLevelSelectEdit">
                    
                <aura:attribute access="public" type="List" name="selection" default="[]"/>
                <aura:attribute access="public" type="List" name="errors" default="[]"/>

                <lightning:card title="Edit Case Type">

                    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="myForm" objectApiName="ERT_Case_Type__c" onsubmit="{!c.onSubmit}" onsuccess="{!c.onSuccess}">
                    <lightning:messages />
                    <c:Lookup selection="{!v.selection}" onSearch="{!c.lookupSearch}" onSelection="{!c.useSelected}" errors="{!v.errors}" label="Search" placeholder="Search Case Types Data"/>
                    <lightning:inputField aura:id="Level_1__c" fieldName="Level_1__c" />
                    <lightning:inputField aura:id="Level_2__c" fieldName="Level_2__c" />
                    <lightning:inputField aura:id="Level_3__c" fieldName="Level_3__c" />
                    <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" />
                </lightning:recordEditForm>
                </lightning:card>
            </aura:component>
```

Any resolution why I am getting this `Case: id value of incorrect type: a3k2F0000007GUpQAMerror ""`

Regards,

Carolyn

Comment: Exactly where are you getting this error? Can you provide debug logs?

Comment: If your lookup field references Case, it appears you are performing a SOSL search against the wrong object, `Case_Type_Data__c`, which would neatly explain the error message.